# Add foreach to my class

Tags: c#, class

I have a test class that I created and I want to be able to create multiple instances of it. Then I want to use foreach to iterate thru each instance. I have seen several forums that show `IEnumerate` but being a very newbe they have me confused. Can anyone please give me a newbe example.

My class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text

namespace Test3
{
  class Class1
  {
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public string   Address { get; set; }
    public string   City    { get; set; }
    public string   State   { get; set; }
    public string   Zip     { get; set; }  
  }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: put each instance in a List - you can then do foreach on the list

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to enumerate through multiple instances of your type, or create a type that is itself enumerable?

The former is easy: add instances to a collection, such as `List<T>()` which implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
// instantiate a few instances of Class1
var c1 = new Class1 { Name = "Foo", Address = "Bar" };
var c2 = new Class1 { Name = "Baz", Address = "Boz" };

// instantiate a collection
var list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Class1>();

// add the instances
list.Add( c1 );
list.Add( c2 );

// use foreach to access each item in the collection
foreach( var item in list ){
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( item.Name );
}
```

When you use a `foreach` statement, the [compiler helps out and automatically generates](http://forums.asp.net/t/1235252.aspx/1) the code needed to interface with the `IEnumerable` (such as a list). In other words, you don't need to explicitly write any additional code to iterate through the items.

The latter is a bit more complex, and requires implementing `IEnumerable<T>` yourself. Based on the sample data and the question, I don't think this is what you are seeking.

- [How do I implement IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789389/how-do-i-implement-ienumerable)
- [IEnumerable vs List - What to Use? How do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628425/ienumerable-vs-list-what-to-use-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 1):

Your class is just a "chunk of data" - you need to store multiple instances of your class into some kind of collection class, and use foreach on the collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create multiple instances in an array

Class1[] instances = new Class1[100];
for(int i=0;i<instances.Length;i++) instances[i] = new Class1();

// Use foreach to iterate through each instance
foreach(Class1 instance in instances) {

    DoSomething( instance );
}
```