# Getting error on making class IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, ienumerable, farpoint-spread

I am trying to inherit the [`FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread`](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/farpointsupportsite/modules/docs/SpreadWin5Help/FarPoint.Win.Spread%7EFarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread.html) class and implement `IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>` so that i should be able to apply linq on FarPoint spread rows or cells. I tried multiple ways but i keep getting errors:

```
class myspread : FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread, IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>
{
    public IEnumerator<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myspread.GetEnumerator();// Error on this line
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Second try:

```
class myspread : FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row, IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>
{
    public IEnumerator<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myspread.GetEnumerator();// Error on this line
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Third try:

```
class myspread : FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cells, IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Cells>
{
    public IEnumerator<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return myspread.GetEnumerator();// Error on this line
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to apply linq on a lot of objects on a FarPoint sheet

Now the above data could be in lacs - i need to do a lot of formatting on the above data and update values on some conditions. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I can't help but notice all three attempts are the same..

Comment: @SimonWhitehead looks slightly different to me (also completely random)... 3 different base classes, 2 different interfaces - should be more variations (which I hope will not appear in the post).

Comment: I think you need to first give yourself at least a *basic* understanding of what an IEnumerable really is.  Thehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789389/how-do-i-implement-ienumerable

Answer (score 1):

In all cases you indicate that the following line is generating the error:

```
return myspread.GetEnumerator();// Error on this line
```

Without knowing more about your code we can't really get to the bottom of this.  It looks like you're trying to call the `GetEnumerator` method statically on the `myspread` class, which is probably not what you'd like it to do.

I assume that you want your class to provide enumeration over the rows in the active sheet.  Looking at the documentation [here](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWin5Help/index.html), and specifically the docs for the [`Rows` collection](http://www.clubfarpoint.com/FarPointSupportSite/Modules/Docs/SpreadWin5Help/FarPoint.Win.Spread~FarPoint.Win.Spread.Rows_members.html), I'll make some guesses about how it might look:

```
class myspread : FarPoint.Win.Spread.FpSpread,
    IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row>
{
    public IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var rows = ActiveSheet.Rows;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; ++i)
            yield return rows.Item[i];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Of course if the `Rows` collection implemented `IEnumerable<Row>` then this would be simply a matter of doing:

```
    public IEnumerable<FarPoint.Win.Spread.Row> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ActiveSheet.Rows;
    }
```

The FarPoint documentation doesn't indicate any support for `IEnumerable<Row>` in the collection however.